# Vite build.sourcemap hidden not loading in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, source-maps, javascript-debugger

Migrating my react app from create-react-app to Vite and seeing some unexpected behavior with source maps. Vite docs regarding source maps are [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-sourcemap). I was leaning toward using `sourcemap: true` until I saw that `sourcemap: 'hidden'` is the same thing except it is supposed to hide my comments ... sounds like exactly what I want.

If I create a build with `sourcemap: true`, each JS file gets its own map file, and the JS file gets a comment like `//# sourceMappingURL=mylibrary-033b4774.js.map` appended at the end of it. The source maps get loaded into Chrome and Firefox as expected.

If I create a build with `sourcemap: 'hidden'`, the only difference in output is that the `//# sourceMappingURL=mylibrary-033b4774.js.map` comment is NOT appended at the end of the JS file. A map file is still produced for each JS file, and it is accessible if I try to access it manually in the browser by typing its full path. However, the browsers don't seem to like this ... they don't show the map at all.

Is this a bug in Vite or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default defineConfig({
build: {
    sourcemap: true,
}
})
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.